# YARN: Exception from container-launch exit code 127

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to submit a `teragen` job to YARN like this:

```
yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar teragen 1000 /teragen
```

It all goes well until it errors out:

```
2021-11-04 23:45:20,540 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1636069364859_0003
2021-11-04 23:45:25,629 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1636069364859_0003 running in uber mode : false
2021-11-04 23:45:25,630 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2021-11-04 23:45:27,658 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1636069364859_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
[2021-11-04 23:45:26.200]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1636069364859_0003_01_000002
Exit code: 127

[2021-11-04 23:45:26.201]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
/bin/bash: line 1: m: command not found
```

I have no clue what the problem is. I've tried looking into the logs, especially the `prelaunch.err` file but it is empty. The `stderr` file has:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: m: command not found
```

Checking the node manager logs, I found this:

```
2021-11-04 23:44:05,765 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
2021-11-04 23:44:06,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 transitioned from LOCALIZING to SCHEDULED
2021-11-04 23:44:06,423 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.scheduler.ContainerScheduler: Starting container [container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002]
2021-11-04 23:44:06,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 transitioned from SCHEDULED to RUNNING
2021-11-04 23:44:06,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002
2021-11-04 23:44:06,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /opt/yarn/local/usercache/vagrant/appcache/application_1636069364859_0001/container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002/default_container_executor.sh]
2021-11-04 23:44:06,477 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 is : 127
2021-11-04 23:44:06,478 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch with container ID: container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 and exit code: 127
ExitCodeException exitCode=127: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.launchContainer(ContainerLaunch.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-11-04 23:44:06,479 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception from container-launch.
2021-11-04 23:44:06,479 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Container id: container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002
2021-11-04 23:44:06,479 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 127
2021-11-04 23:44:06,479 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container launch failed : Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. 
2021-11-04 23:44:06,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
2021-11-04 23:44:06,503 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerCleanup: Cleaning up container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002
2021-11-04 23:44:06,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
2021-11-04 23:44:06,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
2021-11-04 23:44:06,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
2021-11-04 23:44:06,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /opt/yarn/local/usercache/vagrant/appcache/application_1636069364859_0001/container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002
2021-11-04 23:44:06,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
2021-11-04 23:44:06,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002 from application application_1636069364859_0001
2021-11-04 23:44:06,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1636069364859_0001_01_000002
```

I've read other responses and when they mention that Java is missing or `JAVA_HOME` is not set. That's not my case, my `JAVA_HOME` is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

Any idea what could be going on here? Thanks :)

Comment: There is an error in the script... `line 1: m: command not found` is from bash, nothing to do with Hadoop

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, it was actually a memory configuration error. For some reason something was not "living" long enough to actually post the heap size problem. After letting several containers fail and re-attempt to execute the job, I eventually got with the problem. I was going to post the solution in a second.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the memory allocated for each container. Some containers were not living long enough to actually log the error apparently.

But after several attempts I actually got an error that looked like this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap
```

For some reason, the memory configuration for YARN and MapReduce jobs I was using was not correct. I ended up using Ambari's HDP `yarn-util.py` to get the appropriate values for my setup.